# Python word cloud - TypeError: expected string

Tags: python, dictionary, word-cloud

I'm trying to create a word cloud from a list of tuples which has the frequency values for each as below.

[image]

The type(subdict) shows as dict.

My code to create a word cloud is as below:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import random
def grey_color(word, font_size, position, orientation, random_state=None, **kwargs):
    return 'hsl(0, 0%%, %d%%)' % random.randint(50, 100)
wordcloud = WordCloud(width= 800, height = 400, relative_scaling = 1).generate_from_frequencies(subdict)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.imshow(wordcloud.recolor(color_func=grey_color, random_state=3))
plt.axis("off")
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.show()
```

But I'm getting the error: **TypeError: expected string** pointing at the WordCloud()

It works when I have one word each frequency but why doesn't it work when I have a dict of this type?

Updated question:

When I convert the list to str as suggested in the answer, I get the dictionary as follows:

[image]

All words have a frequency of 1. Any reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`generate_from_frequencies()` expects dictionary with `str` as key, you are providing tuple. You need to convert it

```
subdict = {z: y for x, y in freq_dist.items() for z in x}
```

Comment: This creates a list with each word as str and of frequency 1. Screen Shot attached (in the question). I can't understand why. Any explanation @Guy?

Comment: @Nez From what I see in the first image you posted all the values are 1.

Comment: This was just a screenshot of the first part of the dictionary. There are many words.

Comment: I tested it on`freq_dict = {('usps', 'warn'): 1, ('wireless', 'phish'): 2} subdict = {z: y for x, y in freq_dict.items() for z in x} print(subdict)`, the result was `{'usps': 1, 'warn': 1, 'wireless': 2, 'phish': 2}` Do you have an example for input with value not 1 with output 1? @Nez

Comment: @Nez Remove the first `subdict = ` line, use only the code from my answer. You need to take values from `freq_dist`, not from `subdict`.